# Remove unknown network device names listed in network manager

Tags: network-manager, 18.04

I would like to delete enp0s20u5u* devices. How do I do it?

OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

The result of nmcli device status is

```
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
eno1           ethernet  connected     eno1       
enp0s20u5u3    ethernet  disconnected  --         
enp0s20u5u3i5  ethernet  disconnected  --         
enp0s20u5u4    ethernet  disconnected  --         
enp0s20u5u4i5  ethernet  disconnected  --         
rename3        ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo             loopback  unmanaged     --
```

I only have two ethernet connections:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM (rev 05)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

Or at least understand what these are!

----- EDIT ------

I have already tried nmcli delete. Does not help me.

```
sudo nmcli device delete enp0s20u5u4
Error: Device 'enp0s20u5u4' (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8) deletion failed: This device is not a software device or is not realized
Error: not all devices deleted.
```

Answer (score 8):

Those extra entries must be software devices like bonds, bridges, teams, etc.

First locate the names of the aforementioned software devices with `nmcli`

Then use `nmcli device` command to delete any interfaces.

Such as

```
nmcli device delete enp0s20u5u*
```

where enp0s20u5u* is replaced with the software device you found in the previous step.

Note that this only works for software devices like bonds, bridges, teams, etc. Hardware devices (like Ethernet) cannot be deleted by the command.

Source: `man nmcli`

Comment: Is there anyway that I can remove it? Or atleast understand what ports they are?

Comment: Find the package that created it in the first place and remove it. For example vmware player installs new network interfaces(for a software device - virtual machine) on a machine. When vmware is uninstalled those interfaces are uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the connection and not the device: i.e.,

```
sudo nmcli connection delete enp0s20u5u4
```

The connection name might be different, so you may have to find it first:

```
sudo nmcli connection show
```

then delete what it finds for that device

```
sudo nmcli connection delete "Wired connection 1"
```